# SQL Server trigger to copy updated rows into another history table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Basically I want to copy any rows that has been updated into another SQL history table but with additional 'Version' column

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].TriggerName 
ON [dbo].[Users] 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[UsersHistory] ([AspNetUserId], [CreditCustomerId],
                                      [UserName], [GivenNames], [Surname],
                                      [Email], [PhoneNumber], [Active],
                                      [Administrator], [AutomaticSuspension],
                                      [CurrentVersion], [Version], [Notes],
                                      [LastUpdateId], [LastUpdateDate])
        SELECT 
            Id, CreditCustomerId, 
            UserName, GivenNames, Surname, 
            Email, PhoneNumber, Active, 
            Administrator, AutomaticSuspension,
            1,
            (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(VERSION) + 1, 1) 
             FROM [dbo].AspNetUsersHistory
             WHERE AspNetUserId = (SELECT Id from DELETED)),
            Notes,
            0, GETDATE()
        FROM 
            DELETED
END
```

If you do that I am getting an error below

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Basically I want to update the version column for each user so it should have 1,2 or 3 whenever the user changed the detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(VERSION) + 1, 1) from [dbo].AspNetUsersHistory
WHERE AspNetUserId = (SELECT Id from DELETED)),
```

to

```
(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(VERSION) + 1, 1) from [dbo].AspNetUsersHistory
WHERE AspNetUserId = deleted.ID),
```

There is no need for the (Select ID from deleted) - it's a subquery, it can see the parent row it is working on directly.

---

Edited to add

To update all the previous versions of the record to set CurrentVersion false, put this inside the trigger above the insert - it should run first

```
UPDATE UH SET CurrentVersion = 0
FROM dbo.[UsersHistory] UH
    INNER JOIN deleted D on D.Id = UH.[AspNetUserId]
WHERE UH.CurrentVersion <> 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. I also need to update the [CurrentVersion] to false for all previous version.
Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: @ove, you need to have UPDATE Statement before this INSERT statement. Check for the rows with the same userid and run UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that the special table Deleted will contain not just one row, but the complete set of rows that were part of the triggering update statement. So if you update 10 rows in a statement, the DELETED table will have 10 rows in it. This is where your `WHERE AspNetUserId = (SELECT Id from DELETED))` is failing. I would tend to just write them all in the history table with a timestamp, and use a query later if you need to convert to a version number. Version number done in this way will always be problematic.

Comment: I know that. I am hoping there is a fix for it. Still prefer the Version Column as the database has already a Version column in other tables. Keeping it consistent

Comment: Ok, then go with the either a subquery as suggested by @dancingFool, or join to a nested query (select AppNetUserID, ISNULL(MAX(VERSION) + 1, 1) from AspNetUsersHistory group by AppNetUseID) m on m.AppNetUserId=deleted.AppNetuserID

Answer (score 0):

You should not have again one more SELECT statement in the derived table. Just use the id from the SELECT statement as given below:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UsersHistory] ([AspNetUserId], [CreditCustomerId],
                                      [UserName], [GivenNames], [Surname],
                                      [Email], [PhoneNumber], [Active],
                                      [Administrator], [AutomaticSuspension],
                                      [CurrentVersion], [Version], [Notes],
                                      [LastUpdateId], [LastUpdateDate])
SELECT 
            Id, CreditCustomerId, 
            UserName, GivenNames, Surname, 
            Email, PhoneNumber, Active, 
            Administrator, AutomaticSuspension,
            1,
            (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(VERSION) + 1, 1) 
             FROM [dbo].AspNetUsersHistory
             WHERE AspNetUserId = d.Id),
            Notes,
            0, GETDATE()
        FROM 
            DELETED as d;
```

Comment: This is exactly the same answer as @dancingfool

Comment: @TomC,Sorry. I did not go in detail on the other answers. I should have done that. Sorry about that.

Comment: At least your answers agree :)